# Python ioapiTools module can't do basic math operations

Tags: python

I've installed ioapiTools, a python module to manage ioapi format files. The module is supposed to handle file and perform operations on them, including basic arithmetic operations. But something is wrong and when I try to, say, multiply an array by a float or an integer, the result is a zero-valued array (both the array and the float/integer are different from zero).
The module in question creates a temporary variable using cdms2 according to the following syntax:

```
import cdms2 as cdms, cdtime, MV2 as MV, cdutil
import numpy as N
```

..........

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    """
    Wrapper around cdms tvariable multiply
    """

    tmpVar = cdms.tvariable.TransientVariable.__mul__(self,other)

    iotmpVar = createVariable(tmpVar, self.ioM, id = self.id,\
                              attributes=self.attributes, copyFlag = False)


    return iotmpVar
```

But the variable returns nothing but zeros.
Any ideas?

Comment: Small stylistic matter: You don't need to use `\` here--linebreaks within parens (or braces or brackets) are basically ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use ioapiTools, and latest version i found was 0.3.2 from http://www2-pcmdi.llnl.gov/Members/azubrow/ioapiTools/download-source-file . 
unfortunately, the code doesn't seem to catchup with evolution of cdat, which now recommend using numpy instead of Numeric.  automated translation tool may be resolving some problems, but not all.  For example, the class `iovar` (defined in ioapiTools.py:2103) now needs to have `_____new_____` method, as it is a subclass of numpy masked array (i dont know how things are in Numeric).  With that, i seems to have `_____mul_____` working.  i couldn't reproduce your problem though, because i couldn't even get an instance of `iovar` without having `_____new_____` method defined.

i can pass what i got to you if you still need one, but i am sure there are more problems hiding... let me know if you need it though.